# Passing Data to Tab Bar

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make Twitter clone for practice. My backend is Firebase and I have Twitter login.

I managed to implement Twitter login but now don't know how to pass current user uid to all Tab Bar View Controllers.

For now my User model only has id (of string type) and posts (of Post array).

```
class User {

    // MARK: Properties
    let id: String!
    var posts: [Post]?

    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }

}
```

This is my LoginViewController part where user is logged in and now I have to initialize new object

```
// Checks if user is already logged in and transfers them to feed
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
      if user != nil {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Login", sender: self)
      }     
}
```

I have created custom controller for Tab Bar with only one property of user: User?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Login" {
        let intializeUser = User(id: (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)
        let tabBar = TabBarViewController()
        tabBar.user = intializeUser
    }
}
```

But this is not working. Can somebody explain how to elegantly store user uid and then use it with every other View Controller?

Comment: Try `let tabBar = TabBarViewController() as! customTabBarController`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter passed to the function **prepare** - `segue: UIStoryboardSegue` contains your destination (the `UITabBarController`) - if you've set it up correctly in the Storyboard.

So in fact what you have to do, instead of initializing a new object, is to simply get it from the `segue` object:

```
let tabBar = segue.destinationViewController as! TabBarController
```

That will make your code work.

There is a whole new story about the architecture of your app - whether to go for MVC or MVVM, MVP or VIPER. That's related to your question regarding elegant storage of the user ID. I can't give you a direct answer on that as it would be primarily opinion based. Try it yourself, find the right level of abstraction.

For *some* reference, [here](https://github.com/svachmic/ios-url-remote/blob/master/URLRemote/Classes/Model/FirebaseDataSource.swift) is my OSS project where I encapsulate Firebase interaction in an object that provides interface for other View Controllers to use. But again - if you're starting with iOS and/or programming in general, maybe it's not the best go-to architecture for start.